# FREObject.callMethod with FREArray as Argument Error

Tags: java, actionscript-3, air-native-extension

I'm having a problem calling an ActionScript method from Java in my native extension. I don't receive any error when building the actually array, populating it with FREObjects and initializing the ActionScript class with the method I want to call. But when I actually call the method, I receive an FREASErrorException.

**Java Code:**

```
try {
        FREArray freArray = FREArray.newArray("com.industrycorp.extensions.product.IAPProduct", mProducts.size(), true);

        for (int i = 0; i < mProducts.size(); i++) {
            JavaProduct product = mProducts.get(i);
            FREObject[] freArguments = new FREObject[6];
            freArguments[0] = FREObject.newObject(product.getName());
            freArguments[1] = FREObject.newObject(product.getPrice());
            freArguments[2] = FREObject.newObject(product.getDescription());
            freArguments[3] = FREObject.newObject(product.getType());
            freArguments[4] = FREObject.newObject(product.getIsPurchased());
            freArguments[5] = FREObject.newObject(product.getInventory());

            FREObject freObject = FREObject.newObject("com.industrycorp.extensions.product.IAPProduct", freArguments);
            freArray.setObjectAt(i, freObject);

        }

        FREObject resultHandler = FREObject.newObject("com.industrycorp.extensions.result.ResultHandler", null);
        FREObject[] args = new FREObject[1];
        args[0] = freArray;


        resultHandler.callMethod("receivedProducts", args);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        mContext.dispatchStatusEventAsync("message", "Error converting Java Products to IAP Products: "+e.toString());
    }
```

The culprit line is: resultHandler.callMethod("receivedProducts", args). I'm not sure what the problem is. The namespaces are correct and the method name is fine.

**ActionScript Class:**

```
package com.industrycorp.extensions.result {
import com.industrycorp.extensions.IAPController;

public class ResultHandler {

    public function ResultHandler() {
    }

    public function receivedProducts(products:Array):void {

        IAPController.getInstance().setProducts(products);

    }
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just for those that are curious. This object works fine.

**ActionScript Code**

```
    // Test FREObject Creation
    FREObject testObject = FREObject.newObject("com.industrycorp.extensions.TestObject", null);
    FREObject message = FREObject.newObject("FREObject wOrks");
    FREObject[] testArgs = new FREObject[1];
    testArgs[0] = message;
    testObject.callMethod("PrintTest", testArgs);
```

**Java Code**

```
package com.industrycorp.extensions {
public class TestObject {

    public function TestObject() {
    }

    public function PrintTest(message:String):void {
        trace(message);
    }

}
}
```

So it's definitely the FREArray/Array as a argument thats the problem.

Comment: Never played with this before but looking over the code and the help files args is expected to be an array of FREObject and in args[0] you are pushing in FREArray

Comment: I want to pass the Array as an argument though.

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting

Comment: FREASErrorException. The message of the exception is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So although the object name is FREArray, the way you initialize it in Java determines if Actionscript expects a Vector or an Array.

**Initialization of Array:**

```
FREArray.newArray(int numElements);
```

**Initialization of Vector**:

```
FREArray.newArray(String classname, int numElements, boolean fixed);
```

It says very clearly in the documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WS982b6f491d178e6d6565d9b1132a79a012f-7ff8.html

I just overlooked the fact that the constructor doesn't create either, its specific.
Thank you for your help in this issue. I have upvoted your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work or not since i have no way of testing but it is to big for comments so don't mark down if it is wrong.

Looking over the docs it looks like you are creating a vector array and i think  you are getting the error because the parameter in action script is set as an array.

try something like this

```
    public function receivedProducts(products:Vector.<IAPProduct>):void {
        IAPController.getInstance().setProducts(products);
    }
```

[EDIT]

Another issue i think i see is this line of code

```
FREObject[] freArguments = new FREObject[6];
```

The docs say

```
public static FREObject newObject( int value )
Creates an FREObject containing a 32-bit signed integer value.
```

Shouldn't it be

```
FREArray [] freArguments = new FREArray [6];
```

Comment: For the record the documentation says that FREArray could be an ActionScript Array or Vector.

Comment: Have you tried to set it up with no arguments to see if you can just call the function at all?

Comment: Creating an FREObject for a custom class: FREObject.newObject(String, FREObject[])

Comment: I have also tried passing in no arguments, it works fine that way.

Comment: Maybe try passing in a less complex object and add complexity as you get it to work.